# Trying to justify icons left while keeping text center in HTML

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-align

I'm trying to achieve a look where I have all of the icons justified to the left while keeping the text centered and have the text wrap onto another line if necessary. However, I want the icon to be inline with the title. Right now it looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OGDJ.png)

I'm not sure why some of the boxes are stretching vertically and why the icons are floating on the line above the text. Also, some of the text is shifting outside of the grey boxes they are supposed to be in. How do I get every icon/title to look like the top example (ie eye glyphicon with "Look Inside This Chapter" text)?

Here is the HTML code I'm using:

```
<div class="text-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">
</span> <div class="text-center">Teacher Pre-Assessment</div></div>
```

I also tried this code to see if that would work but I'm not having any luck:

```
<div style="float: left; text-align: left"><span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-download"></span> <div class="text-center"> Teacher Post-  
Assessment </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario, you can set the icon position to absolute and then `left:0`. However, that can make the icon just go outside the `.text-left` div. So you need to set its position to relative, because absolute elements are positioned according to the closest ancestor that has position relative.

```
.text-left {
  position: relative
}

.text-left .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Then you're free to position the other elements as you want.

Comment: Now the icons are overlapping the text but your CSS helped the original issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the icons into a pseudo class, so they don't clutter up your html:

```
.text-center {
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-center:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png) ;
  background-size:100% 100% ;
}
```

this basically creates an absolute positioned div in .text-center , thats why .text-center needs some padding so the text doesn't run below the icon.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6mjscdxL/

More Details about pseudo classes: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: In my example fiddle you don't actually need the <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> in the html, I forgot to take it out

Comment: The icons are from Bootstrap so I'm not sure how I would put them in the pseudo class...